# Expanding background image to fill remaining width of screen from edge of another div

Tags: html, css, background, css-float, background-image

I'm not sure what to call the problem I'm having, so maybe that's why I'm also having trouble finding a solution.

I was handed a PSD file to convert into a website and I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to get this background image to behave the way we want.

Below is a visual example of the layout I was given, with some editing for the purpose of this post.

[image: screenshot]

The white column on the left will be a fixed width and we want the skyline image to expand from the edge of the column to fit the rest of the browser's window, expanding beyond the inner "wrapper" between the green lines.

I have tried placing divs within my main wrapper div (green lines) and positioning them absolutely.  I positioned them absolutely, because I also need both divs to fill 100% of the window's height.  This works, but I can't get the width of the right hand column (the image) to fill the remainder of the window.

I set my div's width to 100%, but it's nested within my wrapper div, so it is 100% of the wrapper's width, not the remaining width of the screen.

I'm lost here...am I on the right track, with nesting them inside my wrapper div and positioning them absolutely?  Should I go to a table based layout instead?  I don't know where to begin my search for a solution and I've been stuck for 2 days now.

Here is a very basic example of what I am trying.  As you can see in the CodePen link, the blue div on the right does not extend to fill the remaining window space completely.

**CSS**

```
body { background: #d8d8d8; }
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#left-col {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 330px;
    background: #fff;
}
#right-col {
    position: absolute;
    left: 330px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #3A82A4;
}
#left-content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    top: 40px;
}
#right-content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 590px;
    left: 40px;
    top: 40px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left-col">
        <div id="left-content">
            Left column content
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="right-col">
        <div id="right-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin fermentum hendrerit felis eget blandit. Duis lobortis leo nunc, eget venenatis mauris posuere ut. Pellentesque sed justo tincidunt, tristique arcu nec, euismod massa. Aenean quis ipsum nec lacus ullamcorper scelerisque. Nulla ultricies dui sit amet arcu ornare luctus. Ut cursus ut sem sed sagittis. Phasellus tincidunt sapien non odio lacinia vestibulum.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpYQEw

Comment: Why are you not just attaching the bg image to the body tag?

Comment: Your codepen seems to be displaying the behaviour you want.. the blue div on the right goes the whole way across?

Comment: @Aaron because then the tower will wind up hidden behind the white column at times.  I'm wondering if there is a way to get the image to expand from the upper left corner of where it meets the left column and the menu to fill whatever screen is remaining on the right

Comment: @AnnieMac, it doesn't though.  How wide is your monitor?  If you extend your browser, you will see that the blue div is only 1000px wide (the width of the wrapper), it's just offset by the 330px white column

Comment: @JohnManly why is there a `max-width` of `1000px` on your `#wrapper`? That's why the blue div stops expanding at `1000px`, because that is 100% of the width of its parent (`#wrapper`). Take out `max-width` and put `right: 0;` in place of `width: 100%;` on `#right-col`

Comment: @gaynorvader I was using the wrapper div to center my site's content in the screen and contain it within the center 1000px.  If I remove `max-width: 1000px;` from my `#wrapper`, the `margin: 0 auto;` will have no effect and my content won't be centered anymore.

Comment: @JohnManly Do you want the site centered, or taking up the entire with of the screen? Or do you want the image to overflow the wrapper and bleed out on the right hand side?

Comment: @gaynorvader As you described, having the image bleed out to fill the right hand side, but I also want the actual content of the site centered, as in the picture.

Comment: @JohnManly the only way I can think of doing what you describe would be to get the with of the document using javascript and applying it (minus the left margin and `#left-col` width) to the `#right-col`

Comment: @gaynorvader Yea, I was afraid it might come to that.  I already had this website basically finished, when I got thrown this change to it.  I think I may just tell them we're going to need to re-think this new design...I would prefer not to rely on any scripts for layout purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but I think it's close: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdWLXO;

Basically the `#wrapper` is a quarter of the way from the left side of the page and the image expands all the way to the right hand side. When the window gets too small for the `#wrapper` to display the content and the `#left-col` the below media query removes the left hand margin and makes the `#wrapper` take up the whole page.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
  #wrapper{ 
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Holy s***, I think you did it!  Adding those percentages to the `#wrapper` appears to be the closest thing so far, so I'm going to try and play with this right now, to see if I can get it working.  Thanks!

Comment: I do notice that the content isn't positioned exactly in the center of the screen now, maybe I can make some more tweaks to fix that, but this was definitely a big step in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I just gave it a `width: 150%;` or a unresponsive fixed size of `width: 1500px`

```
#right-col {
position: absolute;
left: 330px;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 150%;
background: #3A82A4;
```

Comment: I tried increasing the width to higher percentages at first too, but that's not truly "fitting the div to the screen" and I don't get the same responsiveness of the background changing size with the window.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your wrapper a fluid container instead

```
#wrapper {
min-width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
```

Then position your left and right elements from there, offsetting your right column by the set width of the left column and left position.

```
#left-col {
position: relative;
margin-left: 330px;
width: 330px;
background: #fff;
float: left;
min-height: 100%;
}
#right-col {
position: relative;
margin-left: 660px;
max-width: 100%;
background: red;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The problem that I see with this method is using pixel-based margins like that to position my content in the center of the screen.  I have a 4k primary monitor and HD secondary, so 330px is a lot different on one than the other and will only "center" the content on one very specific window size.

Comment: I agree, and have been playing with % based layout to achieve the same result- but nothing just yet

Comment: This has had me stumped for a couple of days and I'm about ready to go to my previous design (which I had finished, before I was given this one!), so don't waste too much time.  I appreciate the help though! :)

Comment: No problem - the only (very hacky) way I can think to do it would be to set up a dummy content div (centered via margins) containing the #left-col and #right-col element (right col being 'transparent'). Would allow you to set up a fluid container in the background containing the image, maybe using another div and z-indexes to create the 'cut-off/hidden' effect on the left.. but even that is a long shot. And messy! Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in this way too:

```
[..]
#right-col {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 330px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #3A82A4;
}
#left-content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    top: 40px;
    z-index: 999;
}
#right-content {
    width: 590px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGOyBQ

Comment: I'm not too sure what is going on with your codepen, it looks broken, I think I figured out a solution though.  Thanks